# Using Serilog with Castle Windsor LoggingFacility

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I currently have an application that makes use of Castle Windsor for Ioc. I now want to change the logging framework for log4net to Serilog.

The following configures things for log4net:

```
IocManager.Instance.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config"));
```

There is however no UseSerilog() and looking at how UseLog4Net() is implemented it ultimately calls:

```
LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.Log4net)
```

however the LoggerImplementation enum does not have a Serilog member. So how do I tell Castle to use Serilog as my preferred logging framework?

Answer (score 9):

We didn't release a new version of Windsor with a `Serilog` member in the enumeration, however if you look at the implementation of `LoggingFacility` you'll see that the enumeration members (e.g. log4net) we're just getting loaded by reflection.

You can easily use `LogUsing<T>()` to provide the `SerilogFactory` provided by Castle Core:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing<SerilogFactory>());
```

We also deprecated the Logging Facility's `LoggerImplementation` enumeration in Windsor 4.1.0, `LogUsing<T>` is the recommended method.

Comment: No idea why someone downvoted my answer, but this is the correct solution.